# How to highlight target row and column in one or more tables?

Tags: excel, vba, row, listobject

The following code works to highlight row 1 in `ListObject(2)`

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub 
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Clear the color of all cells
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    
    Set oList = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(2)
    With Target
        'Highlight row and column of the selected cell
        .EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
        oList.ListRows(1).Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    End With

End Sub
```

**Question:** How can I highlight the target row instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Intersect`:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireRow, oList.DataBodyRange)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
End If
```

EDIT:

I would suggest that you add an initial condition to check if `Target` is inside the table. If not, exit.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim oList As ListObject
    Set oList = Me.ListObjects(2)

    ' Only proceed if `Target` is inside the table body
    If Intersect(Target, oList.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Clear the color of all cells
    Me.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireColumn, oList.DataBodyRange)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 24

    Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireRow, oList.DataBodyRange)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 38

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT 2:

If you want to highlight another table's column:

```
Dim oList2 As ListObject
Set oList2 = Me.ListObjects(1)

Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireColumn, oList2.DataBodyRange)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
End If
```

Comment: Why did you use `DataBodyRange` instead of `Range`?

Comment: `Range` includes the table headers, but it seemed you're only interested in the table rows.

Comment: Ahhh. I see what you mean now!

Comment: And `If Not rng Is Nothing Then` means if the target is outside the `rng` it will not apply `ColorIndex`?

Comment: `rng` is the intersection of `Target.EntireRow` and the table body. If there is no intersection (for example if `Target` is a cell below the table), then `rng` is `Nothing`. `If Not rng Is Nothing` means `rng` is something.

Comment: I've added an edit which (I think) does what you intend. I think you meant `> 1` instead of `< 1`. `Count` will always return 1 or more. It's safer to use `CountLarge` here also.

Comment: I understand what you mean now regarding `If Not rng Is Nothing`

Comment: Actually `< 1` allows to click and drag highlighting multiple rows and columns whereas `> 1` only allows one at a time.  Either way works.  Don't think `CountLarge` makes a difference since I won't be handling more than 2.1M cells at a time?

Comment: If you're selecting multiple cells, then get rid of `If Target.Cells.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub`. `Target.Cells.Count < 1` will *always* be `False`, so that condition is redundant.

Comment: What is the significance of `Me`?

Comment: `Me` is the parent worksheet, the one containing this code. Better to use `Me` than `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Why is `Me` better than `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: Because `Me` will *always* be the parent worksheet, and that is very explicit.

Comment: By the way, your edit is great.  However, I wasn't going for that because I have another table right above it `ListObject(1)` with columns I want to highlight.  So I took the path of least resistance and just highlighted the whole entire column since I don't know how to do apply the same highlighter to a separate table.  Reckon I would have to ask a separate question to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Easy. See EDIT 2.

Comment: Since we are on a role here, lol, how do we highlight target columns in hidden rows in `ListObject(2)`?

Comment: Might need a new question for that... probably needs more details :-)